# Neo4j: How to pass a variable to a neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

My config.j2 file looks like this:

```
App_name = abc

cypher: """
            MATCH (n:Node) WHERE (n.APPLICATION='{{App_name}}') AND RETURN n.DESCR
"""
```

The above works perfectly fine when i pass App_name as a command line parameter, but doesnt work if I pass it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using escape of double quotes:

```
(n.APPLICATION=\"{{App_name}}\")
```